# if i switch layout timer execute half code

Tags: java, android

I need a timer that every 5 seconds increments a variable by 1 and I update a TextView where the total of this variable is reported, I tried setting the timer in different ways but every time I try to change layout( i use Intent) and then return to that main, the code that continues to increase the value of the variable works, but the one that updates the textview no..

```
    private void startTimer(){
    timer = new Timer();
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run(){
                    x = x + 1;

                    DecimalFormat formatter1 = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
                    formatter1 .applyPattern("#,###");
                    showTotal.setText(formatter1.format(x));
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000, 5000);
}
```

what can be the reason?

I tried to create a button that forces the update of the textview and the value of the variable x continues to increase, I don't understand why it doesn't also execute the second part

Comment: I'm not sure how it applies to an Android GUI, but if you were working with AWT / Swing then I'd straightaway say the problem was that your GUI updates are not running on the event-dispatch thread.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't know, because if I click the button I created to manually update the textview, this updates it! so theoretically this means that the gui update works, right? also because I update it with the exact same command present in the timer

Comment: It's not a question of whether the GUI works *generally*.  It is a thread-safety issue specifically with invoking methods on GUI components from the timer thread.  At least, that's what it would be in Swing.  That would not likely be an issue with handling events from buttons.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I understand, thanks for the explanation and I'm sorry but I'm a beginner. Can I force the update of the swing? I searched a bit on the internet and was trying with runOnUiThread, but I saw that it doesn't work anyway

Comment: As I said, I'm uncertain how Android differs.  I'd write an actual answer if I could give you specific details.

Comment: Answer may depend on how you create the `handler`.  The handler needs to be associated with the main looper thread.

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution by creating a function to update UI,

```
    public static void updateUI(){
    DecimalFormat formatter1 = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
    formatter1.applyPattern("#,###");
    showPuntiTotali.setText(formatter1.format(vv.getPunteggioTOT()));
}
```

if i call this into the timer instead of trying to directly update TextView, it works